# What does starting max variable to -1 do in python

Tags: python, max

In a game rolling dice to a random integer I have to return the max amount at the end. Each roll has points corresponding to the number rolled. I have seen some people use -1 as starting variable for max why is this?

Comment: It's an easy way of setting an initial value that is sure to be replaced by the first die roll.  Any number you could possibly roll on a die will obviously be bigger than -1.

Comment: Perhaps it is because they always add 1 in a loop or so. But without any code it is impossible to answer this question

Answer (score 1):

max variable is assigned to -1 since in most of the scenarios, the elements among which we have to find the maximum are positive.

for example, if I have a list

```
a = [1,2,3,8,5]
```

and I have to find the maximum, I can declare the max variable to -1

```
max_variable = -1
```

and then loop through the list, and keep checking if the element is greater than max_variable or not.
So as every variable in that list will be greater than the max_varible we defined (-1), the algorithm will cover all edge case scenarios, (like if the list only has one element and that too is 0)

Answer (score 1):

-1 is typically used as a starting point for max calculations, because usually there is a conditional statement comparing to the max value, and negative numbers are rarely the max.

However, in cases where negative numbers are being compared, the max actually shouldn't be -1, instead it should be "the lowest starting value of all expected comparison values".

Using this as an example:

```
    current_max = -1
    if(x > current_max):
        current_max = x
```

Then if x is a positive number, the current max will be set to a new value.

Suppose you had a data set like:

```
    data_set = [-100000, -100, -10]
```

Then setting the starting point for max to -1 no longer makes sense,
because -1 is greater than each of the values in the data set - yet is not a part of the data set itself.

Hopefully this highlights the need to ensure that the starting max value is lower than the rest of your data set - so that in the comparison, it is guaranteed that each member of the data set will be appropriately compared.

Since you're using python though, it is typically better to use the built in function in python for:

```
    max()
```

More information on that can be found here:

https://www.codingem.com/python-how-to-find-the-largest-number-in-a-list/